# Feasibility of a user-defined swap method

Tags: c++, c++11, swap

Thinking about [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49959722/whats-a-reason-to-provide-a-swap-for-the-user-defined-type) I got a thought (given that I'm talking about `C++11`) that a user-defined `swap` should be provided only for types which don't provide a `move semantic`, more precisely a `move assignment` operator ('cause I think it's more common to have a `move ctr` while lack a `move assignment` operator); or the `move ctor` and/or the `move assignment` operator have some side-effects which ain't desired to happen.

Let's see the examples: [ the same as in a linked topic ]

```
class remote_connection
{
public:
  int socket_fd;

  friend void swap( remote_connection& lhs, remote_connection& rhs ) = delete;
}
```

As we have NO provided a user-defined `swap` the code trying to swap objects of a `remote_connection` type calls a `swap` instantiated from `std::swap` which causes a move construction and two move assignments to happen (as [@1201ProgramAlarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49959722/whats-a-reason-to-provide-a-swap-for-the-user-defined-type?answertab=votes#tab-top) indicated).

So, to swap objects a compiler issues: one function call to a `std::swap`, one call to a `move ctr` and two calls to a `move assign` operator. Which leads to 3 `int` copies to make an actual swap.

As a result: **4** function calls and **3** copies.

Let's implement a `swap` method:

```
class remote_connection
{
public:
  int socket_fd;

  friend void swap( remote_connection& lhs, remote_connection& rhs )
  {
    using std::swap;

    swap( lhs.socket_fd, rhs.socket_fd );  
  } 
}
```

As we have provided a user-defined `swap` the code trying to swap objects of a `remote_connection` type calls this user-defined `swap` which causes 3 copies for `int` to happen (create a tmp from a rhs, copy a lhs to the rhs, copy the tmp to the lhs).

So, to swap objects a compiler issues: one function call to a `swap` (found by ADL), one call to a `std::swap(int&, int&)`. Which also leads to 3 `int` copies to make an actual swap.

As a result: **2** function calls and **3** copies.

The user-defined swap won, but what if we add some members to our class:

```
class remote_connection
{
public:
  int socket_fd;
  int a, b, c, d, e;

  friend void swap( remote_connection& lhs, remote_connection& rhs )
  {
    using std::swap;

    swap( lhs.socket_fd, rhs.socket_fd );  
    swap( lhs.a, rhs.a );  
    swap( lhs.b, rhs.b );  
    swap( lhs.c, rhs.c );  
    swap( lhs.d, rhs.d );  
    swap( lhs.e, rhs.e );  
  } 
}
```

Here we have: **8** function calls and **6** copies.
But if we didn't provide the user-defined `swap`, we'd have: **4** function calls and **6** copies.

So, it seems that whatever class we have (derived from a class with plenty members, consisting of plenty sub-objects of built-in and user-defined types) it's more sane, IMHO, to not provide a user-defined `swap`. Not only this, but also such the `swap` is hard to support (if we changed something in  a class and forgot to reflect that changes in the `swap` we get a surprise.)

So the questions is: "If we have no side-effects in `move ctr`/`move assign 
operator` and provide them both, do we have to implement a user-defined `swap`, or is it a good practice to rely on `stl` provided one in such circumstances?"

Sorry for such ammount of **so**, I'm not a native speaker :)

P.S. I forgot to add that we need, IMHO, a user-defined `swap` if we're going to implement a `copy-and-swap` idiom and we've implemented a `move assignment` operator.

Comment: Swap is not really aimed at your own code, but for user in the generic algorithms  (either the standard library or other) that want to "swap" templated objects.  You should obviously implement the best "swap" you can for your class.

Comment: Function calls have no observable side effects in the C++ abstract machine.  Neither does writing ints to local variables.  Things with no obsevable side effects are things compilers are great at optimizing away: assuming they have cost is ignorant.

Comment: @RichardCritten  "Swap is not really aimed at your code..." do you mean a `std::swap` or a user-defined one?

Comment: @IlAImdhh user defined swap. The Standard Library algorithms will call your swap (if you have one) inside some it's algorithms,  It doesn't know what type your classes are and call your swap (if it exists) via ADL, in the hope it is more efficient than the generic `std::swap`.